# AngularJS - Different ng-views for different pages

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have one AngularJS application created using yeoman, grunt and bower. And I am using [Wrapbootstrap ace theme](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0B30DGR).

The login and register page looks different style (You can see it if you click on More Pages on left side menu --> Login&Register).

I thought of creating multiple ng-views for login, register and then other view for remaining (homepage.)

This is what I did. I have one **index.html**.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<!-- CSS styles -->
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
<!-- Javascript imports -->
</html>
```

Then for login and register I hav some common style, so created a page **startup.html** and it has some common style for login and reguster.

```
<html ng-app="startup">
<head>
    <!-- CSS styles -->
    </head>
    <body>

      <!-- Some styles with div and all that are common for login and register -->
    <div ng-view></div>

     <!-- Some styles with div and all that are common for login and register -->
    <body>
    <!-- Javascript imports -->
 </html>
```

Then I have `login.html` and `register.html`,  has some form elements.

```
<div>
<form>
<!-- form elemts -->
</form>
</div>
```

Then I have **home.html**

```
<html ng-app="homeApp">
    <head>
        <!-- CSS styles -->
        </head>
        <body>
    
          <!-- Some styles with div and all that are common for all other pages -->
        <div ng-view></div>
    
         <!-- Some styles with div and all that are common for all other pages -->
        <body>
        <!-- Javascript imports -->
     </html>
```

Then have many other Html pages based on the menu links.

```
<div>
<!-- htmml codes for page -->
</div>
```

Here is my **app.js**

```
var startup=angular.module('startup', []);
var homeApp=angular.module('homeApp', []);

var myApp=angular.module('myApp', ['startup', 'homeApp', 'ngCookies']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterController'
      })
   .when('/home', {
       templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
       controller: 'homeController'
    })
   .when('/document', {
   templateUrl: 'views/document.html',
   controller: 'documentController'
    })
   .otherwise({
   redirectTo: '/login'
    });
}]);
```

And in my **loginController**, if the login is success, I am redirecting to `$location.path( "/home" );`

```
startup.controller('LoginController', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.loginUser=function() {
        var username=$scope.user.name;
        var password=$scope.user.password;
        if(username=="admin" && password=="admin") {
            $location.path( "/home" );
        } else {
            $scope.message="Error";
        }
    };
});
```

But when I run, The login page comes up but without **startup.html** layout.

What I want is, when the path is login, or register, **startup.html** should come up and inside tat only the **login.html** or **register.html** should come. For other paths, it should come up with **home.html** layout and inside that all other html pages will come. In that way, for login and register I can keep one layout which is common for both and for all other pages, I can keep other **home.html** layouts

How can I do that?

Comment: OT: is only a typo error or the `body` tag is not closed?
Not Ot: why are you using 3 different `ng-app` ? do you need to have a multi-page web app?
I recently made an admin panel with AngularJS and I did not need to use different views, thats the power of AngularJS, IMHO.

Comment: That was type error. If you see the bootstrap theme page, For login and register there is different style and after login the page entirely changes with styles. That's what I am trying to do here. When it's login I want to load different html before and after the login/register page. And after login, I want load other html laoyut before and after the html pages. What is the best way?

Comment: @iCode - I am also in the same situation. Were you able to solve it? If so, can you please tell me how?